# StorageException: "Server has terminated the upload session", but only on emulator?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

I am using Android Studio, alongside Cloud Storage and Cloud Firestore, to make my app. The issue I'm encountering is regarding the user updating an image in Cloud Storage.

When I deploy the app to a physical device (in my case, my phone), and try to update the user's profile picture in Cloud Storage, it works fine. But when I try to perform the exact same function, with the exact same code and security rules, it is denied in the emulator. I have no idea what is causing this.

When the user attempts to update a profile picture from the emulator, this is the massive error I am given in the logcat:

```
    User does not have permission to access this object.
     Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
2020-10-13 15:38:35.227 29467-29598/com.example.dailyintaketracker E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:331)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:300)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:224)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:433)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:450)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:441)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.send(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:461)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.uploadChunk(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:420)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:223)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
2020-10-13 15:38:35.227 29467-29598/com.example.dailyintaketracker E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    User does not have permission to access this object.
     Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
2020-10-13 15:38:35.228 29467-29598/com.example.dailyintaketracker E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:331)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:300)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:224)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:433)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:450)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:441)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.send(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:461)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.uploadChunk(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:420)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:223)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
2020-10-13 15:38:35.245 29467-29467/com.example.dailyintaketracker E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    User does not have permission to access this object.
     Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
2020-10-13 15:38:35.246 29467-29467/com.example.dailyintaketracker E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:331)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:300)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:224)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:433)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:450)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:441)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.send(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:461)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.uploadChunk(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:420)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:223)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
2020-10-13 15:38:35.246 29467-29467/com.example.dailyintaketracker E/Error: Failed to upload profile picture to path "/profilePictures/OpWYmEaaHfagPiIIHnKMqtXURzo2.png". The error is: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: User does not have permission to access this object.
```

And this is the function that is being called:

```
public void updateProfilePicture (final Uri imageUri) {
        if(imageUri == null) {
            return;
        }

        String path = "profilePictures/" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() + ".png";
        final StorageReference reference = firebaseStorage.getReference(path);

        reference.putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                    toastShort("Updated profile picture successfully.");

                } else {

                    Log.e("Error", "Failed to upload profile picture to path \"" + reference.getPath() +
                            "\". The error is: " + task.getException());

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Admittedly, this is not a massive issue, as it still works on the actual device, but I'm worried that it might not work on other devices because of this issue. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify the storage rules, if you use Firebase authentications use this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
  match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```

Else use this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
  match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
  }
 }
}
```